# How to get the php dynamic id from the jquery click function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

Not getting alert on the anchor click why this happening .

```
<td id="hovercolor">
    <a class="tt" style="text-decoration:
none;color: black;" href="javascript:void(0);" id="<?php echo
$data->id; ?>"></a>
    <?php echo $data->title; ?>
</td>
```

Script I am using to get the alert is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#new1').click(function() {
        alert('ok');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Where is ID `new1`? `$data->id` will print new1 or just 1?

Comment: have you tried any of the answers?

Answer (score 0):

First wrap you code in a document ready statement,second you may want to use a class if you have multiple items

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
          $('.tt').click(function() {
              alert('ok');
          });
     })

   </script>
```

Comment: You should use `.on` method also in order to attach event handlers for element which are added dynamically.(from answer i think that elements are dynamically).

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai dear fellow romanian he isn't dynamically adding elements so no need for event delegation

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your ID is correct, you may use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to select those elements that are dynamically created. And since the ID are dynamic, you need to created a unique class for the links and use it instead

```
$('table').on('click', '.unique_link_class', function() {
    alert('ok');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change two things in your code snippet:

1) I believe $data->id will print an integer values, so I would suggest to use class instead, which is `class="tt"`

2) second change will be, you should put this function inside `document.ready` jquery function. So the updated jquery code should be,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tt').on('click',function(){    //  Notice that I have used `on` here
        alert();
    });
});
```

Comment: what is the difference from my answer and your answer? you use on and i use click? they do the same thing

Comment: Actually our answers are mostly same but I have explained it in detail, and with old version of jqeury `.click` was there but now `on` needs to be used. When I read the question I was writing my answer, I did not know that you have posted the answer. I saw it when I posted mine.

Comment: i don't see any depreciation flag on the click function https://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 0):

use class name instead  of id . Your id may be integer.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            $('.tt').click(function() {
                alert('ok');
            });
 </script>
```